# C#: default of generic T? is not null; behavior changes with generic constraint

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, nullable-reference-types

I have a generic class that should operate on (non-nullable) reference and value types (parameters, returns ...) but internally needs fields that can be null.

```
using System;

public class Gen<T> // where T : struct
{
    public class Data
    {
        public T? t;
    }

    public static void Write(string s)
    {
        Data d = new Data();
        Console.WriteLine("Default of {0} is {1}", s, d.t == null ? "null" : "NOT null");
    }

    // ... other stuff that uses T and not T? like
    // public T DoSomething(T value) ...
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Gen<int>.Write("int?");
        Gen<string>.Write("string?");
    }
}
```

This code does not produce any errors or warnings when compiled (.NET 5) with nullable enabled.
However the behavior is not as I have expected.

```
Default of int? is NOT null
Default of string? is null
```

While playing around searching for a solution, I discovered that when the `where T : struct` constraint is added (and Gen.Write() removed), the behavior changes to

```
Default of int? is null
```

It's odd that a constraint changes the behavior.

Does anybody know a elegant solution to write such a generic class?
Using a custom Nullable class that supports reference types too or a separate bool flags for every T? filed is a bit tedious.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-11-25.md#problem-1-t-and-t-mean-different-things

Comment: The topic above is very close to my case. In my application I need to have a field and hence a type that can be null or hold a T and this for all kinds of T. If T is a nullable reference type, this is already to case. For a non-nullable reference type, the corresponding nullable reference type (C# T?) is needed and for a value type Nullable<T> (C# syntax T?) would be the type needed. I could not find a way to express that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `Nullable<int>` you shouldn't use `int`, so use:

```
Gen<int?>.Write("int?");
```

Then the output will be

```
Default of int? is null
Default of string? is null
```

---

> The code in the question is an example. The real class does not have a
> `Write` method and never uses the string of the type. However as I
> indicated by 'other stuff' it uses T as well as T?. So it is not
> desired to instantiate it with `int?` instead of `int`.

First i want to explain why it's not odd that the `struct` constraint in the generic class changes the behavior. Because actually that constraint makes it compile if you are < C#8. Then `T?` means `Nullable<T>`, so if you use `Gen<int>.Write("int?")` the field `t` will be a `Nullable<int>`. But then `Gen<string>.Write("string")` won't compile at all since `string` is not a `struct`. So it has a completely different meaning with the constraint.

With C#8 enabled you can remove the `struct` constrained, then `t` remains an `int` and the `string` will be a nullable `string`. So the question mark has the meaning: in case of a reference type it's a nullable reference type, otherwise it's just what it is.

You can't have both, a generic type that can be a nullable reference type or a nullable value type without using the desired generic type, so use `int?` if it must be nullable.

Comment: OP: I'd also recommend to output `T.GetType().Name` instead of `s`, so you know the _actual_ type, not the type you anticipate.

Comment: Yes, maybe that was the reason of the misunderstanding. But `d.t` is `null` so you can't get the type from it in that way.

Comment: Yes, right. Maybe something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/r1P4WL

Comment: @FIldor: You are modifying the class just to store it's type. Maybe you can use OP's code in `Write` and remove the parameter and replace it with: `Type t = typeof(T); Type genType = t.GetGenericArguments().ElementAtOrDefault(0); string typeName = genType != null ? $"Nullable<{genType}>" : t.Name;`

Comment: ... ahhhh, yep. Think I'm going to grab a coffee. :D - but anyway, the basic idea is to output the actual type, not what OP is "thinking it should be" ...

Comment: @Fildor: Enjoy, good idea :) I think it's not only about the output but that OP thought that `int` in a generic class will be automatically converted to `int?` if `T` is nullable.

Comment: The code in the question is an example. The real class does not have a Write method and never uses the string of the type. However as I indicated by 'other stuff' it uses T as well as T?. So it is not desired to instantiate it with int? instead of int.

Comment: @p.g.: edited the answer, i don't know if it helps. I'm currently still on <C#8 so not really an expert but i think my explanation should be correct.