# Nullable default parameter with generic type on class

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, type-constraints

I have type with one generic type argument, that contains a method with and an optional parameter. The code treats the nullability of that type in an unexpected way when constructing the default argument.

This is closely related to
[Nullable default parameter with generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68757608/nullable-default-parameter-with-generic-type/)
where a good solution for a function was given.

In the case of a class however, is there a way to write this without creating two copies of the same class, one with a value type constraint, and other handling reference types?

Thanks!

```
public static void Main()
{
    int? @defaultInt = default;
    Console.WriteLine(defaultInt is null ? "null" : defaultInt); // null!

    Test<int> t = new();
    t.Do(); // 0! not null

    Test<object> o = new();
    o.Do(); // null

    TestS<int> ts = new();
    ts.Do(); // null
}

public class Test<T>
{
    public void Do(T? p = default)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p is null ? "null" : p);
    }
}

public class TestS<T> where T : struct
{
    public void Do(T? p = default)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p is null ? "null" : p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Struct inherits from object. Can you do Test<T> where T : object?